# How to get everything from the list except the first element using list slicing

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

So I have something that I am parsing, however here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

And using list slicing have it return to me everything but the first index. So in this case:

```
['B', 'C']
```

I have been messing with stuff like list[:-1], list[::-1], list[0:-1], etc. But I can't seem to be able to find this out.

What I am actual doing is:
* I have a error message that has a error code in the beginning such as:

```
['226', 'Transfer', 'Complete']
```

and I want to just display Transfer Complete on a popup widget. Of course I am casting to a string.

Thank you for all help, and if answer differs via Python 2.7.x and Python 3.x.x Please answer for both versions.

Thanks, looked a lot around stackoverflow and python tutorials couldn't really quite get what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to start at the second element, so use `list[1:]`.

Comment: Don't you need `[1:]` ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks that worked!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks that worked! Really appreciate it!

Comment: `" ".join(lst[1:])` to make `Transfer complete`

Comment: @cricket_007 is that an alternative of doing .split( " ") [1:]?

Comment: Split returns a list. Slicing returns a list. String Joining returns a string, so no, it's the inverse, not alternative

Comment: @cricket_007 oh sweet I think that is exactly what i am looking for let me try it!

Comment: use list.skip(1)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can just do [1:].
This will work on both versions.

Answer (score 57):

It can be done like this:

```
list[1:]
```